# Will FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure() conflict with built in MVC4 validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

Looking at the code in [FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure()](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/88255e1fbd1970770b8d3ee5469cabeadb180fa1/src/FluentValidation.Mvc4/FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.cs#L65)

> DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes
>   = false;
>       ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(provider);

It looks as though it may be impacting the MVC4 built in model validation?

Is it safe to use Fluent Validation and the defacto mvc4 validation together in different view models?

Answer (score 0):

Placing a built in mvc [Required] attribute as well as the fluentvalidation [Validator] attribute on a single class appears to only result in the [Required] attributes validation in the error messages.

This would suggest that not only can they live together in the same project ok. The MVC validation appears to override the fluent validation when on the same class... at least that's what I've found so far.